How to force trailing slash in WordPress pagination links
I'm working on a theme for WordPress and need a trailing slash added to every post list pagination link.
The situation:
Permalink structure is set to /%postname%/ (with trailing slash). All links to pages have the trailing slash.
On the blog page (and any other post list) I have a pagination rendered with this code:
echo paginate_links(
                array(
                    'base'      => get_pagenum_link() . '%_%',
                    'format'    => /page/%#%/,
                    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text' => '<i class="pagination-icon m-icon m-icon-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . __( 'Previous', 'multi' ),
                    'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'multi' ) . '<i class="pagination-icon m-icon m-icon-long-arrow-right"></i>',
                )
            )

The problem
The pagination works, but it seems there is some redirection I don't want. Each link in the pagination looks like this: http://example.com/blog/page/X, where X is the page number, or example: http://example.com/blog/page/2 (notice no trailing slash).
This URL is in the page's markup.
When I click it, the browser goes to the respective blog page, but when the page finishes loading the URL has a trailing slash, like this: http://example.com/blog/page/2/ (Which is OK for me).
When i type http://example.com/blog/page/2 in the address bar I also get http://example.com/blog/page/2/ after page loads.
Long story short:
http://example.com/blog/page/2 in pagination HTML,
http://example.com/blog/page/2/ in address bar after page load
I want the trailing slash in the HTML too.
I tried changing the format argument, adding filters, for example:
add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'trailingslashit' );
and even writing my own functions adding the slash, all with no effect.
Is there any way I can force the trailing slashes in the html of the pagination?
